# What is an example of a "custom function" and "recursion"

Tags: javascript, recursion, custom-function

I have been asked to show I have used these processes in my program but from looking up the definitions, I don't know what they mean. I am confident my program is complicated enough that it uses these processes, but I don't know exactly what they are. What would be an example of these processes used in javascript?

Answer (score 1):

Unsure what you mean by custom function - but recursion is just a function that calls itself.

Example of recursion

```
countNumTimesToZero = (myNum, count = 0) => {
  if (myNum - 1 === 0) return count + 1;
  return countNumTimesToZero(myNum - 1, count + 1);
}
```

Comment: "recursion is just a function that calls itself..." *directly or indirectly*.